# Phinx migrate - enum column with default value

Tags: psql, phinx

While adding phinx migration, Is it possible to addColumn enum with default value?
To achieve:
1. All existing rows to have the default value ('active' in this case)
2. All new entries to have the default value ('active' in this case)

Something I am building up is:

```
$this->table('my_table')
            ->addColumn('status', 'enum', ['values' => ['active', 'cancelled', 'expired']])
            ->create();
```

//how to add 'active' as default?

Answer (score 2):

I am running Phinx 0.5.0, and the way I accomplished the default value for an ENUM type is by adding in the `'default' => ''` option.

Example:

```
public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('example');
        $table->addColumn(
            'example_column',
            'enum',
            array(
                'values'  => ['abc','def','ghi'],
                'default' => 'abc'
            )
        )
            ->update();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does phinx actually understand the rollback in this situation? As far as I read in the documentation it doesn't so should you be using change here?